# Is Exploratory testing Context Driven testing?

Tags: testing, theory, methodology

I do not think so, yet many sources say it is.
As I understand it:

*Context-driven testing means that when planning testing on our project, I choose the methods, practices, etc. in order to fit the context. I choose the approach*

While *exploratory testing is a just a method of testing, where testers explore certain part of the application and dynamically design and run test cases,possibly exploring new areas and new tests.*

I know Exploratory testing is related to context-driven but I do not believe it means the same.

Is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a bit like asking if emacs is agile. The two don't really equate. If you are into the context-driven testing movement, then exploratory testing is one sort of testing you might do given the current context.

Exploratory testing, in and of itself, isn't context-driven testing. It is exploratory testing, much like unit testing also isn't context-driven testing. Exploratory testing is one of many types of testing one can do for a software project.